# How to use Javascript keyboard events for web UI

Tags: php, user-interface, dom-events, javascript-framework

I'm interested in using JS events such as right\left arrow, space bar etc.
Wondering what's the right way to do it. I would like to slide photos, make DIVs appear etc. on such user interactions.

I thought of possible implementations with jQuery such as http://api.jquery.com/event.which/
Though I'm not sure that's the best way.

Here are two good examples for such UI implementations
(How do they do it?)
http://www.thesixtyone.com ;
http://www.pictorymag.com/showcases/summer-jobless

I'm more a C# person, looking for the right direction to dig in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery or plan to, taking advantage of `which` is not a bad idea. If you look at the example, it shows you exactly how to do it. Put your cursor in the text field there and press the key that you're interested in, i.e. left arrow. The number that is displayed in `keydown:` is the code you're looking for.

Now, when you write your own function, you might bind `keydown` to the `document` and listen for the correct keys. From there, you can dispatch certain behaviors depending on which key was pressed.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    var code = e.which;
    switch (code) {
        case 39:
            // code to execute when right arrow is pressed
            some_right_arrow_action();
            break;
        case 37:
            // code to execute when left arrow is pressed
            some_left_arrow_action();
            break;
    }
    return;
});
```

You asked how sites like Pictorymag.com handle this functionality. Here's what Pictorymag.com does (I've decompressed their code to make it easier to read):

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 39:
        case 74:
            node = s[++curr];
            if(node) {
                $.scrollTo(node,800);
            } else {
                curr = s.length-1;
            }
            break;
        case 37:
        case 75:
            node = s[--curr];
            if (node) {
                $.scrollTo(node, 800);
            } else {
                curr=0;
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly how I assumed it could be implemented with jQuery, as shown in their example. I didn't find anything similar in the two sites I gave as implementation examples, so I thought there might be a different, more appropriate approach. any idea how they do it? and Thanks!

Comment: PictoryMag.com uses essentially what I've posted: `$(document).keydown(function(e){switch(e.keyCode){case 39:case 74:node=s[++curr];if(node){$.scrollTo(node,800);}
else{curr=s.length-1;}
break;case 37:case 75:node=s[--curr];if(node){$.scrollTo(node,800);}
else{curr=0;}
break;}});`

Comment: TheSixtyOne.com has obfuscated their code a bit and they use an object-oriented approach, so I can't really post anything succinct here, but the code is in here if you want to try and work it out: http://www.thesixtyone.com/site_media/javascripts/thesixtyone.v16041.js

Comment: Great, Thanks. I'll do it that way. Where did you find it in the PictoryMag.com code? Is there a way to read \ understand something from the obfuscated TheSixtyOne code?

Comment: PictoryMag.com's code is in here: http://static.mypictory.com/static/CACHE/js/ecb5cdac854f.js

Comment: There may be some tools out there that attempt to deobfuscate JavaScript, but I haven't used any of them so I don't have any recommendations. Failing that, it'll just take some time studying of TheSixtyOne.com's code to figure out how it works. To start with, search for the parts that mention "keydown" or "keycode", and look at their event handler function "_getEv()". Add tabs and linebreaks back into the code to make it easier to read, and start piecing it together.